# How does one specify multi-line strings in Typesafe Config?

Tags: typesafe-config

I have the following configuration file that I want to use from Scala applying [this library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/examples/scala/simple-lib/src/main/scala/simplelib/SimpleLib.scala):

```
P11 {
    yes="0.0"
    no="1.0"
}

P12 {
    yes="0.01"
    no="0.99"
}

P13 {
id = "123 567 \
T 0: \
If (f 23 <= 0.0)"
}
```

This is how I do it:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

val configFileName = "/usr/develop/tests/config.conf"
val parsedConfigMCF = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(configFileName))
val confMCF = ConfigFactory.load(parsedConfigMCF)
```

Then I get the error:

`Expecting a value but got wrong token: 'newline' (backslash followed by 'newline', this is not a valid escape sequence`

It looks like it does not like `\` (backslash), but I need to put several lines for `id` in `P13`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#features-of-hocon) of Typesafe Config:

> multi-line strings with triple quotes as in Python or Scala

so:

```
P13 {
  id = """123 567
  T 0:
  If (f 23 <= 0.0)"""
}
```